# .htaccess started redirecting images

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I've been messing around my website (which was working yesterday) and by mistake I've rewritten my .htaccess file with blank one (wanted to duplicate the file in one folder into different folder, but messed it up making it rewrite root folder's .htaccess), so I'm trying to make one again (yes I know, should have had backup).

Now to the problem: I was editing unrelated thing in my .htaccess file, and suddenly the images stopped showing, being redirected to my 404 error page instead. It looks to me like the Apache suddenly started ignoring my certain `RewriteCond` rules, as css and javascript rules normally work, and it's driving me insane.

I've tried to search everywhere, but haven't found the solution.
This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index_new.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index_new.php?sekce=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index_new.php?sekce=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2&podpodsekce=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2&podpodsekce=$3&podpodpodsekce=$4 [NC,L]
```

The question was marked as DUPLICATE, but I've tried the solutions (before writing the question) and they do not work, as I use absolute paths to images too, but I cannot get to them regardless.

Comment: `RewriteCond`s only affects the directly following `RewriteRule`, not all of them ...

Comment: But instead of now repeating all those conditions before every rule, you should rather place on single rule after them that does no rewriting at all, and just uses the L flag to say don’t process any more rules in this iteration. (Off the top of my head, something like `RewriteRule .* - [L]` should do.)

Comment: I need the htaccess to rewrite my urls, so if I do page.com/articles, it passes page.com/index_new.php?sekce=articles internally. I understand that the RewriteCond only affects the first rule, but only one rule should match, depending on ammount of parameters passed. My question is also if it's possible to explain why images from root folder do work, and images from root/images folder don't.
EDIT: If I use your rule, the page throws 403 Forbidden

Comment: Images from the root folder do work, because only your first rule would match anything that doesn’t contain any /, and that rule has the conditions before it preventing it from working on images as well. As soon as you go into a sub-folder, the second rule becomes the one that applies - but that has no restriction whatsoever on images, so it rewrites the request to index_new.php ...

Comment: I used the L flag in my first RewriteRule, and according to informations I've found, this should stop execution upon sucesfully matching the rule. I still see no solution to the problem. It displayed images fine just a while ago, and suddenly it doesn't. Also CSS and JS files work on all "cases" (doesn't matter how many parameters I use).

Comment: But if you request `images/foo.png`, your first rule does not match to begin with ...

Comment: My aim was to EXCLUDE images from matching the rule. That is the reason for my RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC] etc.
Did I understand the way it works incorrectly? Does RewriteCond not PREVENT the redirection? Now I found out interresting thing: I've deleted all in my file, copied my question's text in it, now the images load but page.com/articles doesn't work. page.com/articles/0 works thought. This is some super wierd behaviour that I cannot explain.

Comment: But this exclusion of images only works on the one single RewriteRule that follows those conditions ... When you request `images/foo.png`, your first rule does not match - so the conditions preceding it can result in whatever they want, it doesn’t matter. // Try this approach maybe, that is a lot simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29132656/1427878

Comment: Edited my comment to make more sense. I've played around with those solutions already (mentioned in your comment), but it did not do what I needed. I need to rewrite urls to "nice adress" and internally send the right request to index_new.php. I used to have working .htaccess file that did all this while images worked too. It contained a line stating file extensions, but I cannot find the solution I used when I was making the file earlier.

Comment: The way people usually do this these days, is you only check whether what was requested was not an existing folder or file - and then just use one single rule to rewrite everything else to your script file. Then you make use of $_SERVER to figure out which URL was actually requested - and then do your splitting of that into separate parameters in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I will definitely try this solution, but that will require me to rewrite the handling of the files completely, while I need to just hotfix the website as it needs to run until I come up with different solution.
My problem still persists, images out of folder do not load, when I try to manually enter the adress of the image in my browser, it instead redirects me to 404 error document. Rewrites work (I can go to site.com/article/0 and it will display like supposed to), so I would need some hotfix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the backup from the webserver provider. If anyone would have same kind of problem, the working code is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|gif|js|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index_new.php?sekce=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2&podpodsekce=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index_new.php?sekce=$1&podsekce=$2&podpodsekce=$3&podpodpodsekce=$4 [L]
```